# Broken link URL for badge

Tags: discussion, broken-link

I was reading this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133698/353283) and found lots of broken links, for example the URL https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54/electorate seems to be about the gold Electorate badge, but try it; it goes to: Help Center > Badges > Enthusiast. Here is another one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor

Comment: You already fixed the links so....

Comment: @Cai but its still there, in my post, look at the end of the url and click on link, why is it happen, in my opinion it's confusing and sort of bug that should fix not post by post.

Comment: You mean the badge name in the URL? That doesn't actually do anything.... replace it with anything, say, [cheese](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/65/cheese), and you still get the page for the correct numbered badge.

Comment: @cai i thought it's better to go to "404 page not found"

Answer (score 1):

This site you're on used to be Meta Stack Overflow, and those links used to go to the correct pages. A long time ago, this Meta was split off to its own site and Stack Overflow got a normal per-site Meta. Since the badge ID numbers are not always consistent across sites, and the links were never updated to use this site's URL, they started pointing to different badges than what they indicated.

All that's needed is an edit to fix the links. There is no bug in the system.