# Can the 'receive your first Gold Badge' description be changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, profile-page

Every time I notice the following suggestion, I get slightly amused:

[image: Suggestion on how to earn your first gold badge]

> You don't have a gold badge yet. Write an answer that scores 100 or more to earn your first.

I think this is not helpful advice at all, and even comes off slightly derisive, especially on smaller sites (perhaps anything smaller than StackOverflow, actually).
With my entire, more than 3-years old network profile, I have received just one of these Great Answer badges, and it was certainly not my first.

There are gold badges that are arguably [easier to obtain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133631/422926) (e.g. the Fanatic, Copy Editor, Electorate, and Steward badges do require much more time, but are guaranteed and can even be tracked).

**Wouldn't it be better if this 'advice' were changed, or at least randomized, that upon visiting your profile this message would be randomly selected from the pool of gold badge descriptions?**

Comment: It’s unlikely that “Fanatic” is chosen as the example description since it uses a [“potentially toxic metric”](/q/368285/289905). Other than that, you’re right. Marshal is probably also relatively easy to get, especially on Meta Stack Exchange where lots of spam and off-topic questions get posted every day.

Comment: @SebastianSimon since this is shown to every user including new users, possibly only badges related to asking/answering/editing are applicable from the start. Marshal, while relatively easy, needs 15 reps to flag.

Comment: Actually the suggestion is misleading. A few days ago I got 115 points on a bountied question. No gold badge materialized. There must be some additional constraint.

Comment: @Andrea A "score of a 100" is actually a 100 upvotes, resulting in 1000 reputation points :) A 115 suggest 10 upvotes and acceptation of the answer (worth 15 points).

Comment: @Joachim Thanks, that clarifies the issue! Still, the bounty is assigned on the basis of 1 upvote (i.e. the acceptance vote of the bounty setter). One may still wonder whether a 1000 bounty yields a gold badge.